# $stateParams in angular decodes URL param inconsistently

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application I'm saving a query string (user typed search string) in the URL. 
I have a `model={query: 'blabla'}` and I use `$location.search(model)` to update the URL with my param.
When I hit refresh, or navigate to another state and back, I get the query param using `$stateParams.query`, then I assign it to the search box model.

Consider the next scenario:

user search: `aa/bb/login?f=Student%20Home11`

the URL: `...?query=aa%2Fbb%2Flogin%3Ff%3DStudent%2520Home11`

(note that forward slashes are encoded to %2F, and that %20 is encoded to %2520, as I would expect, because the %20 is a literal phrase the user typed in, not an encoded space).

**the problem:**

after navigating to another state, that also has `query` in its state params in ui-router (in order to keep the value in the URL when switching between those states), and then navigating back:

`$stateParams.query:`aa%2Fbb%2Flogin%3Ff%3DStudent%20Home11`

as if `%2520` was decoded to `%20` but all other encodings (`%2F`) stayed encoded.
Then if I decode it I get a space (instead of `%20`) in the search box.

In a second scenario, after hitting ***refresh*** (the URL obviously stays the same):

in `$stateParams`: `aa/bb/login?f=Student%20Home11`
as should be - all forward slashes are decoded and also the '%' sign was decoded but the '%20' stays literally `%20`.

What happened in the state transition that causes this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem.
When I used `$state.go()` to move between states, I didn't send $stateParams between states, so when I got back from the other state, it probably parsed the URL params instead of getting the params from the state.
Working now.